# How to take back my bounty?

Tags: feature-request, bounty

In the case you set a bounty for your question and gave it to someone but after trying the accepted answer it did not work: how could you take back the bounty and let the question open again for a useful answer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[That is not possible](https://askubuntu.com/help/bounty): **All bounties are paid for up front and non-refundable under any circumstances.**

1. You should have checked the answer before awarding the bounty;
2. You can flag the answer. That might get it deleted but the bounty is not going to return to you.

Comment: For which thing are these reputations useful apart from having certain edition privileges ?

Comment: @begueradj - "how can you let the question open again" ... you basically dont accept the answer if it wasnt useful to you.  BTW - I'm sure you could have got a great answer to your question.  As per my comment on your question, there wasnt any real detail to your question to enable a great answer :(

Comment: @begueradj the more rep you have the more likely the person can be trusted to give accurate answers :)